# How to suppress warning that gcc option is deprecated

Tags: gcc, arm, deprecated

I'm using the [official release of ARM GCC 2018 Q4 Major](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads).  For this C code:

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

the compiler produces a warning:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mstructure-size-boundary=32 main.c
cc1.exe: warning: option '-mstructure-size-boundary' is deprecated
```

Is it possible to suppress this warning?  The flag `-Wno-deprecated` has no effect.

I need to use the `-mstructure-size-boundary` option because I need to link against someone else's closed source compiled libraries that used the same setting.  (Well, I guess I could edit their headers and manually set trailing struct padding but that would not be Plan A).

Comment: It was deprecated somewhere between gcc 7.4.0 and 8.1.0. Can you user an earlier version of gcc? (I see no information in `ChangeLog-2017` or in the git log about *why* it was deprecated, but there's more information [here on the "gcc-patches" mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg169032.html).

Comment: I'm guessing that ignoring the warning isn't an option. Perhaps you have a build system that fails if gcc prints anything to stderr. The `-w` option inhibits all warnings, but that's probably overkill. You could write a wrapper script that invokes `gcc` and filters out just that warning.

Comment: I have the same question about the -I- option: https://github.com/att/ast/issues/20.